# Using current libraries, how would I make simple encryption/decryption methods for a text string?

Tags: java

I understand the security issues with this and that this is not much more secure than storing the text in plain text, but I just want to see it done.  I've found plenty of various topics on this subject, but none that do something simple like this:

```
String secret = "aooi3jpoiqjalknflkjn34lakjn3fkna3;a3f";
String encryptedText = encrypt("This is a sentence", secret);
String decryptedText = decrypt(encryptedText, secret);
System.out.println(decryptedText);
```

This has nothing to do with homework, work, or an assignment, I'm just messing with a program that sends emails and if I can store the password in something other than plain text I'd prefer it.  I'm not looking to create a hash that compares the values in a database, I just want to store a random string of characters in a file then use a hard-coded secret to decrypt it.

I also understand that I could do this simply with creating my own algorithm to mutate the secret into the string, but I was hoping there was a specific library I could use for doing this instead.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: The encrypting process is normally - Generate a key for encryption and decryption of your data. When your data needs to be encrypted, it needs to read in a data stream instead of pure String or text, so you need to convert your data. It's possible to simplify to the way above too by creating your own encrypt / decrypt methods using those standard encryption library.

Answer (score 1):

I have full example that does this in my Git repo: [DesEncryptionExample](https://github.com/CoachEd/JavaExamples/tree/master/DesEncryptionExample). It works like this:

C:\Temp> java MyEncrypt oranges.jpg mypa$$99
file written: encrypt.bin

C:\Temp> java MyDecrypt encrypt.bin mypa$$99
file written: decrypt.bin

C:\Temp> rename decrypt.bin oranges2.jpg

C:\Temp>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses but I think I came up with what I was looking for:

```
public class EncryptText {

    private final String SECRET_TEXT = "baamx2maeaacxbmc";
    private final String CIPHERTYPE = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private final String ENCODING = "UTF-8";
    private final byte[] SECRET;
    private final SecretKeySpec key;
    private final byte[] initializationVector;
    private final IvParameterSpec ivspec;


    public EncryptText() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        SECRET = SECRET_TEXT.getBytes(ENCODING);
        key = new SecretKeySpec(SECRET, ALGORITHM);
        initializationVector = new byte[]
            {1, 4, 3, 4, 10, 125, 64, 105, 13, 17, 10, 1, 7, 13, 0, 12};
        ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(initializationVector);
    }

    public EncryptText(byte[] iv) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        SECRET = SECRET_TEXT.getBytes(ENCODING);
        key = new SecretKeySpec(SECRET, ALGORITHM);
        initializationVector = iv;
        ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(initializationVector);
    }


    public String encryptString(String string) throws 
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, 
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException, 
            BadPaddingException {

        byte[] inputBytes = string.getBytes(ENCODING);
        Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHERTYPE);
        encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivspec);
        byte[] encryptedData = encryptCipher.doFinal(inputBytes);
        return String.valueOf(new BigInteger(encryptedData));
    }

    public String decryptString(String string) 
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, 
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

        BigInteger value = new BigInteger(string);
        Cipher decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHERTYPE);
        decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivspec);
        byte[] decryptedData = decryptCipher.doFinal(value.toByteArray());
        return new String(decryptedData);        
    }

}
```

From here I can take the encrypted string and place it somewhere then use the decryptString method to decrypt it.

Edit: As a note I haven't done anything with error handling yet as I was just doing the minimum to get this to work.